# How to access the each element individually in Three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have created  mesh and rendered " 10 " 3d objects using three.js?

how  to access  each object to perform scaling , rotation & all stuffs so there is a
need to get the div object individually?

help me to solve this issue ?

thanks !

Comment: could you post some code or make it easy to replicate your setup ? I not sure if you've created 1 or 10 mesh instances.

Comment: Here is the start up code , look into tat code patch & help me to handle the meshes dynamically ! ! ! !  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/gui. .. . .

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be asking a real question. But rather asking for someone to teach you something. In the 'startup code' a SphereGeometry object is combined with a MeshBasicMaterial object in order to create the Mesh object which is your 3d object that you can then use to access/set the objects position, rotation, etc. Here are the lines of code I am referring to:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 75, 20, 10 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Once you create mesh objects you need to add them to the scene with a call to scene.add(mesh). At this point you can set or get the rotation or position as such

```
mesh.position.x = 50;
mesh.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2 // rotations are in radians
```